# Navigating to different UIs from GWT Menu bar

Tags: gwt

I am new to GWT. For my application, I want to make a Menu Bar on the left and navigate to different UIs by clicking on the Menu items. Is there any way I can do this through GWT? I want to know whether I can do that through execute() function of MenuItem.

Thanks

Comment: Where are you stuck? Is GWT confusing you? :)

Comment: Yes :). I am not getting how to go to different links through menu bar items.

Comment: What have you done? Please share some code piece to fulfill it as per your requirement because It's not clear from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to study Activities and Places design pattern in GWT:

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html

It explains how you can create multiple views in your application, and navigate from one view to another.

EDIT:

In the execute() method of a ScheduledCommand that you passed to a MenuItem you call

```
placeController.goTo(new MyPlace());
```

as explained in the Activities and Places documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have already read that. I was thinking whether I could do it through having a menu bar on the left side. When I add a menu item to menu bar, I see the execute() function. I am just not getting how to implement that to navigate.

Comment: Activities and Places can be used on any side :)  I updated my answer.

Comment: I have been using Thomas Broyer's solution for activity nesting and it worked for exactly what you are doing. I had a navigation activity and a content activity each with there own ActivityMapper. This works great!! It is a little more boiler plate but is extremely extensible and flexible. http://blog.ltgt.net/gwt-21-activities-nesting-yagni/

Comment: @Andrei I just did.. Actually this is my first post, so I didn't know.